# Why can't I convert this string into an integer?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

No mater how I try this I keep getting the same error I need to get a user input using the `JOptionPane` and then convert it to an integer.

This is my code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // Imports JOptionPane class.

public class MailOrderEMH {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare string variables
        String title;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String streetAddress;
        String city;
        String state;
        String zip;
        int numBoxes;
        int count = 1;
        String enterAnother = "Y"; //INITILIZE the loop control variable


        //Conver srring to integer
        numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number of Boxes: "));

        //get input values from user
        title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your title ex. (Ms. Mr. Dr.) ");

        //get input values from user
        firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Name: ");

        //get input values from user
        lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Last Name: ");

        //get input values from user
        streetAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Street Address: ");

        //get input values from user
        city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter City: ");

        //get input values from user
        state = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter State: ");

        //get input values from user
        zip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Zip Code: ");


        while (count <= numBoxes) {
            System.out.println(title + firstName + lastName);
            System.out.println(streetAddress);
            System.out.println(city + state + zip);
            System.out.println("Box" + count + "of" + numBoxes);
            count = count + 1;
        }
        //get input values from user
        enterAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Do you want to produce more labels? Y or N ");

        while (enterAnother.equal("Y" || "y")) {
            //get input values from user
            title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your title ex. (Ms. Mr. Dr.) ");

            //get input values from user
            firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Name: ");

            //get input values from user
            lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Last Name: ");

            //get input values from user
            streetAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Street Address: ");

            //get input values from user
            city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter City: ");

            //get input values from user
            state = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter State: ");

            //get input values from user
            zip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Zip Code: ");

            //get input values from user
            numBoxes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number of Boxes: ");
        }
        // End program.
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

And this is the error

```
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
            ( "Enter Number of Boxes: " );
```

Comment: I think you are not saved your file before compiling.

Comment: @LEQADA I am for sure saving it so I have no idea what's wrong. I added my full code to the question. could something in that be causing the error

Answer (score 0):

What is this in while statement `enterAnother.equal("Y" || "y")` ? 
It must be

```
while (enterAnother.equals("Y") || enterAnother.equals("y"))
```

And in this line

```
numBoxes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                    ( "Enter Number of Boxes: " );
```

You are trying to convert String to int. You need to use parseInt this way

```
numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                ( "Enter Number of Boxes: " ));
```

Comment: I am saving the java file

Comment: here's the rest of the code is it something further down that's messing it up

Comment: thank you that helped but now in getting a new error that says error: variable numBoxes might not have been initialized
 while (count <= numBoxes).   do you know what that could be about

Comment: @Grace, `Integer.parseInt` throws `NumberFormatException`. So, `numBoxes` might not have been initialized. Give it a value in declaration `int numBoxes = 0;`.